# VB.NET Declare/Retrieve list items as a whole without using For Next

Tags: vb.net, list

I declared

```
Public siList As New List(Of Decimal)
```

as a list of decimal, and added data into it by using

```
siList.Add(CurrencyTextBox48.Value)
```

Then Retrieved the list contents using

```
 For Each si As Decimal In siList
            FleetDialog.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = si
        Next
```

Now my question. Is there any way to declare a variable like *si* and get all decimals in siList without using For Next? I really need to call si as a variable outside a for next statement.

Comment: You're not explaining what you're trying to achieve but why not add a second variable of type decimal?

Comment: My question is all about retrieving all contents of a list. For Next which is included in my question is the only way I can think of to get all list items inside siList. What I need now is to get all list contents of siList using a variable **outside** a for next. For me to call si which is declared in the for next outside of it.

Comment: I haven't understand the context of your question but there is the embedded function `siList.ForEach()`, using a delegate, which might help.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to add the value from the list into a cell and you want to do it multiple times. Are you looking for something like Rows(i).Cells(0) = siList[i]?